# How to convert Plot to PiePlot3d for creating a 3d pie chart using jfreechart?

Tags: jfreechart, pie-chart

I am trying to create a simple 3d pie chart using jfreechart in NetBeans IDE.My code is given below :-

```
DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
pieDataset.setValue("One", new Integer(10));
pieDataset.setValue("Two", new Integer(20));
pieDataset.setValue("Three", new Integer(30));
pieDataset.setValue("Four", new Integer(40));

JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Pie Chart", pieDataset,true,true,false);
PiePlot3D plot = (PiePlot3D) chart.getPlot (); // <--error in this line
```

However, the last line shows the error "Incompatible types : Plot cannot be converted to piePlot3D"  . Many examples i found on the internet uses the same line of code without any error. I have included all the necessary imports but still the error is shown. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [createPieChart3D()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createPieChart3D-java.lang.String-org.jfree.data.general.PieDataset-) method in the [ChartFactory](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html) class (you missed the '3D' on the end of the method name).

You should also look at the 3D pie charts in [Orson Charts](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/) - these use real 3D projections, so they are a bit nicer.  I am the author of both libraries.